# Можно ли называть объект?

Tags: json

```
{
    "data":[
        "бегемот": 
            {
            "name": "котлета",
            "grade":"5",
            "letters":"к",
            
        },  
        
       "носорог": {
            "name":"носорог",
            "grade":"5",
            "letters":"н",
              
        }
  
}
```

Можно ли называть объекты?

Comment: да, можно называть. Но не так как в примере

Comment: Можно но не рекомендуется использовать тсе кроме utf8. Они на много медленнее и весят больше

Comment: @Grundy А как называть?

Comment: например так : `var бегемот = {"name": "котлета","grade":"5","letters":"к"}`